# Работа с RS-232 в Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial, com-port

Всем привет.
Есть прибор управления поворотным устройством. В нем присутствует COM-порт (RS-232) для управления с ПК.
Известно из документации к прибору, что порт работает в режиме 9600-8N1. Также известны команды для управления. Например:

'Y' - возврат текущего положения углов
'S' - немедленная остановка
'Qaaa.a eee.e' - команда на установку положения с азимутом aaa.a и углом места eee.e

Итак, изучив описание матлаба попробовал написать следующий код:

> s = serial('COM1')
>
> fopen(s)
>
> fprintf(s, 'Q100.0 100.0')
>
> fprintf(s, 'Y')
>
> fscanf(s)

Так вот, на отправку команды fprintf прибор никак не реагирует. На fscanf выдает следующее:
Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached..

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как проверить что команды идут на порт? И почему на них нет никакой реакции. И что это за терминатор такой.

Прибор проверен, работоспособность на управление через COM-порт проверено через фирменное ПО.

Comment: В вашем примере не видно кода задания параметров порта, как минимум. Проверка того, что данные идет осуществляется путем подключения второй машины к порту.

Comment: По умолчанию в матлабе последовательные порты создаются с параметрами 9600-8N1. Правильность кода проверено с помощью программы,  создающая два виртуальных спаренных порта. Данные передаются в любом направлении.